# Vim won't work after upgrading ubuntu to focal fossa

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, vim

I was using vim built from source, with ruby support on ubuntu 18.04. After upgrading ubuntu to Focal Fossa, its not working anymore. I get the following error in the terminal

```
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libruby-2.5.so.2.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Other Information that may be helpful, output of `ruby --version` returns

```
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

`whereis vim`

```
vim: /usr/bin/vim.tiny /etc/vim /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/share/vim /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
```

`type -a vim`

```
vim is /usr/local/bin/vim
```

How to fix this problem, do I need to rebuild vim again?

Comment: Add the output of `type -a vim` and `apt-cache policy vim` to the post please. Use code formatting for command output: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @muru If OP built Vim from source, then `apt-cache policy vim` would be useless.

Comment: @Melebius oh, didn't notice that. (I thought it was a PPA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you built Vim for Ubuntu 18.04 yourself, you’ll probably need to rebuild it with the updated dependecies. As you have found already, Ubuntu 20.04 uses [`libruby` version 2.7](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libruby) while your binary is looking for 2.5 as it’s [present in 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libruby).